# How to compare monthly parcial date with MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a parcial date with my select. For intance, we are in the 10th of april so i want to consider the data from 1st of April untill the 9th of april. At the same time i want to compare the date from the last month on the same period (from 1st of March until 9th of March).

Can someone help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)